# Case based Joins in oracle query

Tags: oracle, join

I have below query which returns all the data from inner query including one more field i.e. ctry from tbl_account table.I have used
LEFT JOIN so that even though a_row_id not matched with row_id from tbl_account so that i would still get all the matched data from inner query.

```
     select b.* ,sac.ctry as country from
    (SELECT DISTINCT rec.* ,asset.a_row_id
               FROM tbl_record rec LEFT JOIN tbl_asset asset
                    ON asset.from_sn = rec.to_sn
                  AND asset.from_name = rec.to_productname
                  AND asset.from_rel = rec.to_rel
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_country mas
                    ON rec.loc = mas.a_loc                                                                       
              WHERE rec.cust_id = 2456 ) b     
              LEFT JOIN tbl_account sac on b.a_row_id = sac.row_id ;
```

But,now i need to implement case based join in the above query i.e. when a_row_id is not null then inner join with one extra condition will be used and when a_row_id is null left join will be used.
I have tried using CASE statement as below but it is not working and cost of the query is very high as well and I suppose it is because of CASE statement.The 
data in all the tables are in millions.

```
 select b.* ,sac.ctry as country from
 (SELECT DISTINCT rec.* ,asset.a_row_id
               FROM tbl_record rec LEFT JOIN tbl_asset asset
                    ON asset.from_sn = rec.to_sn
                  AND asset.from_name = rec.to_productname
                  AND asset.from_rel = rec.to_rel
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_country mas
                    ON rec.loc = mas.a_loc                                                                       
              WHERE rec.cust_id = 2456 ) b     
              INNER JOIN tbl_account sac   
              ON CASE 
                 WHEN b.a_row_id IS NOT NULL AND b.a_row_id = sac.row_id and b.from_cn = SAC.to_cn THEN 1
                 END = 1
              LEFT JOIN tbl_account sac
              ON CASE 
                 WHEN b.a_row_id IS NULL AND b.a_row_id = sac.row_id THEN 1
                 END = 1 ;
```

Is there any other way that i can implement case based joins condition in above oracle query and at the same time cost of query would be less.Is it possible to use decode in this case ? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, `WHEN b.a_row_id IS NULL AND b.a_row_id = sac.row_id`... this won't return anything; you're saying that if b.a_row_id is null, see if sac.row_id = null. Quite apart from the fact that `<something> = null` will aways return null in Oracle, it doesn't really make sense to do that. My gut feeling is that you could do this with one join, using `or`s in the join condition. Assuming that you've got the correct join conditions, ofc! *{;-) It would help if you could update your example with some sample data along with the expected output, so that we can test the query ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is probably what you are looking for:

```
select b.*, sac.ctry as country
  from b  
  left join tbl_account sac 
    on b.a_row_id = sac.row_id or (b.a_row_id is null and sac.row_id is null)
  where b.from_cn = sac.to_cn or b.a_row_id is null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9182c/1)